# Using Azure DevOps Services with Azure DevOps on-prem Repos and Build/Release. Is that doable?

Tags: azure, tfs, build, azure-devops, release

Here's the scenario.  We currently use Azure DevOps 2019 Server for all team related work.  This also includes our Repos and Build/Release mechanisms.  All done on-prem.   We are considering move the scrum work to Azure DevOps Services but would like to keep the Repos and B/R portion on-Prem.  Would that be doable and still be able to tie workitems to builds, etc?

If not, if we move all of it to the cloud, I am assuming that the build servers will need internet access (probably port 443) so that the builds could happen locally or would we need to those in the cloud as well?

Comment: Why would your build servers need to move to the cloud? You can connect them to Azure DevOps the same as you would connect them on-prem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst doable, I'm pretty sure workitems wouldn't be linked as the Azure Devops Team Project is its own instance and so is the on-prem Devops 2019 instance.

Best is to move it all to the cloud, rather than try and get a halfway-house solution set up.